# Import a script tag with a js file to head firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've tried to inject a script tag with a js file on my extension to a page. But I cant make it work.

I have the same extension on Chrome and there works.

This is my "contentscripts.js" file:

```
var scriptDatePicker = document.createElement('script');
scriptDatePicker.src = browser.runtime.getURL('jquery.daterangepicker.min.js');
scriptDatePicker.onload = function() {
    this.remove();
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(scriptDatePicker);

var scriptFunctions = document.createElement('script');
scriptFunctions.src = browser.runtime.getURL('functions.js');
scriptFunctions.onload = function() {
    this.remove();
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(scriptFunctions);
```

It's seems the files are injected, but for one reason the "daterangepicker" doesn't. And this is the proof:

[image]

The dateRangePicker function is in the "daterangepicker.min.js".

Is there another way on firefox to do this? Inject a script tag with a js file src?

Just in case, this is my manifest.json:

```
{
    "name" : "My Extension",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "description" : "My extension description.",
    "permissions": [ "cookies", "https://*/*", "http://*/*", "tabs", "activeTab"],
    "browser_action": {
      "default_popup":"popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["*://samplepage.com/*"],
        "js": ["contentscripts.js"],
        "css" : ["daterangepicker.min.css"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
      }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["jquery.daterangepicker.min.js", "functions.js"],
    "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like FF may be changing the order of execution. Try moving the entire second block of your code inside the onload callback in the first block. BTW do you really need it as a DOM script not as a normal content script?

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes, its necessary because I need that functions on the main page. BUT, I put the code in the first onload, just like u told me and its works! Thanks! but, why did that happen? I mean, I want to learn the why. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @wOxxOm, the problem was the order of execution in the contentscripts.js.

I change the contentscripts.js to:

```
var scriptDatePicker = document.createElement('script');
scriptDatePicker.src = browser.runtime.getURL('jquery.daterangepicker.min.js');
var scriptFunctions = document.createElement('script');
scriptDatePicker.onload = function () {
    scriptFunctions.src = browser.runtime.getURL('functions.js');
    scriptFunctions.onload = function () {
        this.remove();
    };
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(scriptDatePicker);
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(scriptFunctions);
```

And it works.

Thanks for the help!